# Transferring table to table

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, foreach

```vb
 MySQLConn = New MySqlConnection
 MySQLConn.ConnectionString = Connection
 Adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
 Dim QRY = "SELECT EquipmentID, Quantity FROM subdbborroweq"


 Dim TimeAndDate As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
 Dim EQIDArr As New ArrayList
 Dim QTYArr As New ArrayList
 Try
     MySQLConn.Open() 
     Command = New MySqlCommand(QRY, MySQLConn)

     Dim QRY1 = "INSERT INTO borrowlogs( `BorrowerName`, `EquipmentID`, `Quantity`, `TimeDate`) VALUES (@Uname, @EQID, @QTY, @TAD )"
     Dim Command2 = New MySqlCommand(QRY1, MySQLConn)
     Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
     While Reader.Read()

         EQIDArr.Add(Reader("EquipmentID"))
         QTYArr.Add(Reader("Quantity"))

     End While
     Reader.Close()
     Dim i As Integer = 0


     For Each eqid As Integer In EQIDArr 
         For Each qty As Integer In QTYArr
             Command2 = New MySqlCommand(QRY1, MySQLConn)
             Command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", AddBorrower.TextBox1.Text)
             Command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EQID", eqid)
             Command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QTY", qty)
             Command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TAD", TimeAndDate)
             Command2.ExecuteNonQuery() 
         Next 
     Next

     MySQLConn.Close()
     AddBorrowerIntoBorrowerForm.Close()
 Catch ex As MySqlException
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
 Finally
     MySQLConn.Dispose()
 End Try
 AddBorrower.Close()
```

I have this codes that supposedly transfer one table set to another table but add some details and enhance it, I have problem in the

```vb
 For Each eqid As Integer In EQIDArr 
     For Each qty As Integer In QTYArr
         Command2 = New MySqlCommand(QRY1, MySQLConn)
         Command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", AddBorrower.TextBox1.Text)
         Command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EQID", eqid)
         Command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QTY", qty)
         Command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TAD", TimeAndDate)
         Command2.ExecuteNonQuery() 
     Next 
 Next
```

Part. Can anyone help me with this loop? My problem is when I press the button it input the table times to it's column count. Please anyone help me with this loop?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a loop for this?  You can simply use `insert . . . select`.  It is a little hard to follow the logic that you are trying to do, but this might put you on the right track:

```
INSERT INTO borrowlogs( `BorrowerName`, `EquipmentID`, `Quantity`, `TimeDate`)
    SELECT AddBorrower.TextBox1.Text, EquipmentID, Quantity, NOW()
    FROM subdbborroweq;
```